# Getting error no route to host while using ssh command

Tags: networking, ssh, playonlinux

Im using Linux in virtual box with network setting bridged adapter when I earlier used to use ssh command for connecting to site it used to get connected and now while I m trying to connect it say no route to host in between once I changed my network setting to NAT bt then restored bridged network how can I get rid of this? 
Ping to the site is working I tried to connect through other system bt shows same error

Comment: did you set the vm to use a static IP address .. if not did you check to see of the IP is the same or if it got changed by DHCP?

Comment: No I haven't set it to use static IP

Comment: This error happened to me today, my problem was default port which is 22 but my remote server is on another port (2270)